# How to convert GeoCoordinate to real address with GoogleMaps API?

Tags: c#, api, google-maps

I buy `GoogleMaps api` to use it in my project, and I get the string to use it.
I have a `GeoCoordinate(lat,long)` and I want to convert it to `real address (like "New York, USA")`. how can i do it?

Comment: You can do it using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that using `Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)`
 `geocoding`  refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is called as reverse `geocoding`.

> [**See documentation for Reverse Geocoding**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse#try-it-yourself)

Instead of supplying a textual address, supply a comma-separated latitude/longitude pair in the location parameter.

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)